# recurrence relations and generating functions - I need a hint

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I need to find "closed form" to the recurrence relation given by:  $a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0} ^ {n} k a_{n-k}$ and $a_0 = 1$. I have tried using generating functions but it is no good. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look to the first terms; there is a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is to reshape the given recurrence relation. Move the left hand side to the right giving $0=\sum_{k=-1}^nka_{n-k}$ for $n\geq0$. Then rename $k$ and $n$ such that both have values $1$ more than before, giving $0=\sum_{k=0}^n(k-1)a_{n-k}$ for $n\geq1$. Finally incorporate the initial condition in the modified form $\sum_{k=0}^0(k-1)a_{n-k}=-1$. So the recurrence relation and initial condition can be captured in
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^n(k-1)a_{n-k}=-\delta_{n,0}
\qquad\text{for all $n\geq0$.}
$$
Now the equation states an easy relation between generating functions: with $F=\sum_k(k-1)X^k$ and $A=\sum_la_lX^l$ it states $FA=-1$.
This means that $A$ is the inverse generating function of $-F$. Expressing $-(k-1)=2-(k+1)=(-1)^k(2\binom{-1}k-\binom{-2}k)$ and using the binomial formula for exponents $-1,-2$ gives
$$-F=\frac2{1-X}-\frac1{(1-X)^2}=\frac{1-2X}{(1-X)^2},$$
whence
$$A=\sum_la_lX^l=\frac{(1-X)^2}{1-2X}=1+\frac{X^2}{1-2X},$$
where the last equality results from a [polynomial division by rising powers](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_d%27un_polyn%C3%B4me#Division_selon_les_puissances_croissantes) of $(1-X)^2$ by $1-2X$. It leads to an explicit expression solving the recurrence: $a_0=1$, $a_1=0$, and
$a_{i+2}=2^i$ for $i\geq2$.

Comment: Note that $A = 1+x^2/(1-2x)$.

Comment: @martycohen: Thank's, I've extended the equation.

Comment: It's also $\big\lfloor\frac{2^{|n-1|}}{2}\big\rfloor$ just for the sake of knowledege

Comment: @user114138: True, at least for $n\geq0$, but I'm not sure it is more informative then my final sentence.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It's most certainly not. You're answer is the only one relevant. I just added it for fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $n\geq1$ one has:
$$a_{n+1}-a_n
=\sum_{k=0}^nka_{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}ka_{n-k-1}
=\sum_{k=1}^nka_{n-k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)a_{n-k}
=\sum_{k=1}^na_{n-k}.$$
Thus, $a_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^na_{n-k}$ for $n\geq1$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Define the generating functiom:

$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$:

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \sum_{0 \le k \le n} k a_{n - k} z^n \\
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
  &= \left( \sum_{n \ge 0} n z^n \right)
       \left( \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \right) \\
\frac{A(z) - 1}{z}
  &= \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2} A(z)
\end{align}$

Solve for $A(z)$, as partial fractions:

$\begin{align}
A(z)
  &= \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2} z + \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
\end{align}$

Thus:

$\begin{align}
a_n
  = \begin{cases}
      1          & n = 0 \\
      0          & n = 1 \\
      2^{n - 2}  & n \ge 2
    \end{cases}
\end{align}$